# Workflow to Copy Document to List (Link to Document)

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to copy a document from a SharePoint 2016 Library into another Library, but as a link.

I'm trying to copy a file (B2BAddEditDelete.docx) from one library into "Test Library" using the Link to Document Content Type, but the workflow is failing, giving this error (site collection and library names replaced with italics):

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 7/18/2019 11:07 AM. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://`SITECOLLECTION`/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@Folder)/Files/Add?%40Folder='%2F`LIBRARYNAME`%2F`SITECOLLECTION`%2F`LIBRARYNAME`&url='B2BAddEditDelete.aspx' Correlation Id: bd862c57-6d90-c4a7-ad76-3ba868ed5684 Instance Id: 94f10296-0db0-4d78-bc60-d9136d628ccb

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

I think this is tied to the Path and Name field, but can't figure out a workaround-any tips? My workflow is below:
[image: 2013 SP Designer Workflow]

Comment: Did wrapping your flow in an app step work out for you? Have you been able to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I would need to test this out a bit, but try wrapping your entire workflow in an APP Step, it may be a permissions issue

Edit: Please also try placing yourself in a group that has EDIT or Contribute permissions as well. Sometimes the workflow can be finicky and not function properly, even if you are a site collection owner. I have seen this happen before

Comment: I'm set up as the Site Collection Owner with Full Permissions, so I'm not sure what the APP step would do differently-do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the workflow is just finicky. Please give it a shot and let me know the results

Comment: Also, sometimes even though you are a site collection owner, you sometimes have to be in an OWNER, MEMBER or group that has edit/contribute permissions when the workflow is executed. Please try placing yourself in a member group as well and trying that.

Comment: I added myself to both the Owners and Members Groups of the Site, and both Libraries, but I'm still getting the error message below when I run the workflow. For context, the source library is called Sales Documents, and I'm trying to create a Link to Document copy in TestLibrary. The error is split over 2 comments due to character limit

Comment: (1)
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to https://[Site Collection]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@Folder)/Files/Add?%40Folder='%2FTestLibrary%2FB2BManageCarts%2C+https%3A%2F%2F[Site Collection]%2FSales%2520Documents'&url='B2BManageCarts.doc%3Fweb=1.aspx' Correlation Id: 4ff78d45-fdb6-8de6-bc31-02d056ae61d9 Instance Id: 30e7831e-d03f-40c2-9320-80c408a7bf9b

Comment: (2)
The file or folder name "TestLibrary/B2BManageCarts, https://[Site Collection]/Sales Documents/B2BManageCarts.doc?web=1.aspx" contains invalid characters. Please use a different name. Common invalid characters include the following: # % * : < > ? /  |

Comment: One of the problems here is that you are using the encoded URL as the Path/Name in the destination library, the file name is trying to get a special character which will Fail..... Try just using the file name for the Path/Name column, and put the encoded URL into a Single Line of text field column in the destination library

Comment: When I try that, I get the below error. 

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Unauthorized to https://[Site Collection]/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@Folder)/Files/Add?%40Folder='%2FTestLibrary'&url='B2BQuoteRequests.aspx' Correlation Id: 4ff78d45-fdb6-8de6-835d-277627495369 Instance Id: 34c977f9-4b75-4762-869a-cfb25fc84fd6 

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Comment: I'm currently in the Owners (Full Control) and Members (Edit) Groups for both libraries (inherits permissions from site) so I don't know what I would do in an APP step workflow-but we haven't used those in our site at all either

Comment: I am running into some issues on my own workflow servers,so I can't replicate your issue quite yet.... couple of questions though. 1 Did you try and wrap the workflow in the app step? If not please just "try" that as well. Also, just to confirm, you are using SP 2016 and using sharepoint designer 2013 workflow? or 2010?. Thanks

Comment: Also, are you in the group explicitly? or is it from an AD defined group? This is important as well.

Comment: Rachel, Also try just using a normal Document content type for this workflow instead of Link to Document. I know I have given you a few different things, try a few of these and report back. Thanks!

Comment: We created a SharePoint Owners group, where I'm listed explicitly. I'm also in the Members group explicitly and through an AD Group.

I tried changing the document type to Document, but that didn't work either. We don't want to copy the document (owned by another department), we want to create a link to a document for a Landing Page for end users.

Comment: We don't have the “Workflows can use app permissions” setting enabled. I've asked our IT admin to set that, and I'll try the app step once that's set up